# Variable define inside loop, used outside with end value?

Tags: c#

Regarding the `F3` variable. Can I use it outside the loop as such, or how else can I achieve what is intended below?

```
for (int i = 3; i == sequence; ++i)
{
    int F3 = F1 + F2;
    Console.WriteLine(F3);
    F1 = F2;
    F2 = F3;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine($"The {sequence}th number of the Fibonacci sequence is :{F3}");
```

Comment: `F2` is always equal to `F3` at the end of each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This code makes no sense

Comment: Just declare `int F4 = 0;` outside the loop.  Then inside the loop add `F4 = F3` and display that.  Or declare `F3` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are only visible inside the block where they are declared. Since you are declaring `F3` inside of the loop body, it is only visible inside of the loop body.

If you want to use it outside of the loop body, you will also need to declare it outside of the loop body. Like this:

```
int F3;
for (…)
{
    F3 = F1 + F2;
    // …
}
Console.WriteLine(F3);
```

That being said, in your case, at the end of the loop body, there is a line `F2 = F3`, so after each loop iteration, `F2` will be equal to `F3`. And since `F2` appears to be declared outside of your loop body already, you can just use that variable instead.

Also note that your loop condition is wrong. You are checking `i == sequence`, so your loop will only continue when `i` is equal to `sequence`. Since `i` is changing on every loop iteration, that can only be true for a *single* `sequence` value of `3`. So it’s likely that your loop does not run at all. What you meant to do is check `i <= sequence` so the loop continues until you hit `i == sequence`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't add that "sequence" is basically user input.

What you said about defining the variable outside the loop. Well If I did define int F3 as you did, would F3 hold the end result value of the loop afterwards?

Comment: I figured that `sequence` was user input, but it still is a fixed value, so it does not update while the loop iterates, so you will still have to fix your loop condition. And yeah, `F3` will hold its value after the loop, just like `F1` and `F2` do.

Comment: Wait. Say sequence == 13. Wouldn't the loop run from i == 13 until i == 13 with a i++ step?

Comment: The loop starts with `i = 3`. Then it checks the loop condition `i == sequence` which is false because `3` is not equal to `13`. So the loop terminates without executing. – You want to check `i <= sequence`.